# How do I tell what referral url my httprequest says it's coming from?

Tags: javascript, youtube, xmlhttprequest

I'm sending an xmlhttprequest to youtube to get some videos. I have gone to the google developer's console and set up an api key with WORK URL I'm requesting from connected to it. When I try to run the script from WORK URL, I get an 'ipreferrer not allowed' error, even though I specified that url on my api key.

But when I connect the api key to MY OWN PERSONAL URL and run the same script from that url, it works fine. So when it's run from WORK URL it must be sending the wrong referral url to youtube.

The question is, how can I tell what referral url my xmlhttprequest is telling youtube it is coming from?

My code is below:

```
function createCORSRequest(myurl, cb)
        {
           var xmlhttp;
           if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
               xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
           else{
               xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    if( typeof cb === 'function' )
                        cb(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }

           xmlhttp.open("GET",myurl,true);
           xmlhttp.send();

        }


        function buildVideoMenu()
        {
            openDiv = true;
            mainVideoTarget = 'main_video';
            playlistID = 'PLAg45-Ox3WR4gODmcAmIYHVvCpngXcCTZ';
            menuDiv = 'video_menu_images';
            thumbnailDiv = 'thumb';
            APIKey = 'AIzaSy...';
            url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?' +
                    '&part=snippet' +
                    '&maxResults=25' +
                    '&playlistId=' + playlistID +
                    '&key=' + APIKey;
            //alert(url);
            createCORSRequest(url, function(srchJSON)                       //Get JSON for search
            {
                myDivHTML = '';
                myDiv = document.getElementById("video_menu_images");               //get div in variable
                console.log("YouTube returned the json code: " + srchJSON);
                
                srchObj = JSON.parse(srchJSON);                             //parse JSON for playlistItems
                for(i=0;i<srchObj.items.length;i++)                         //For items in srchObj.items:
                {
                    console.log("item number " + i);
                    if(srchObj.items[i].snippet.thumbnails!=undefined)
                        {
                        if(openDiv)
                        {
                            myDivHTML += '<div id = "tnvertblock">';
                        }
                        myDivHTML += '  <div class = "' + thumbnailDiv + '">';
                        //console.log(srchObj.items[i].snippet.title);
                        vidFrameURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + srchObj.items[i].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                        //console.log("url = " + vidFrameURL);
                        imgUrl = srchObj.items[i].snippet.thumbnails.default.url;   //get thumbnail image url
                        myDivHTML += '          <a href = "' + vidFrameURL + '" target = "' + mainVideoTarget +'">';
                        myDivHTML += '          <img width = "120" height = "90" class = "thumbnail"  src = "' + imgUrl + '" />';
                        myDivHTML += '          </a>';//            Put in the item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url (its own div)
                        myDivHTML += '  </div>';                        //close thumbnail div
                        if(!openDiv)
                        {
                            myDivHTML += '</div>';
                        } 
                        openDiv = !openDiv;
                    }
                }
                //alert(myDivHTML);
                myDiv.innerHTML = myDivHTML;                        
            });
         
        }
                    
                
        buildVideoMenu();
```

UPDATE: To clarify my question, here's a screenshot of the console developer's page with an explanation:
[image: console screenshot]

Comment: So you send it from a different domain than what the api key was registered from? Of course it will not work, you need an api key for each domain.

Comment: No, that's not what I said. I also connected the api key to MY OWN PERSONAL URL to test if the script worked. You can allow as many referrers as you want. So both referrers were allowed. But it only worked from my personal url, not from the work url.

Comment: I added a picture to clarify what is going on.